# 2 <ion-input> na mesma linha IONIC 2

Tags: ionic2

Estou com um problema no meu projeto com IONIC 2, preciso inserir 2 campos de texto na mesma linha. Já tentei fazer isso usando , quando coloco somente texto dentro dele funciona , mas quando coloco o  ele não é exibido.

Segue abaixo o trecho do html que estou com problemas:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col width-50>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Minímo</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valorMinimo"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-50>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Máximo</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valorMaximo"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, o problema era a tag `ion-item` fora da tag `ion-grid`. Apenas removi e funcionou:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Minímo</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valorMinimo"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-50>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Máximo</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valorMaximo"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```